# How do Express router.param and router.route work in terms of defining URL parameter names?

Tags: node.js, express

I created a router file using Express. The callback functions reside in their discrete "controllers" files. Following is an excerpt of the parts relevant to my question, and lines such as `require` of controller functions have been omitted:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// This should run first
router.param('coolParamName', validateParamBeforeHandlingReqs);
// Param name is ↑↑↑↑↑ "consumed" here, although NOT defined yet

// This should run after the above code
router.route('/').get(getAllUserNames).post(createUser);
router.route('/:coolParamName').get(getUserName).patch(updateUser).delete(deleteUser);
// Param name is ↑↑↑↑↑　defined here, and was consumed earlier - how?
```

As the comments explain, it seems like the param name has been defined as `coolParamName` on the *bottom*, but "consumed" by the code written *above* it. This feels strange to me, because I feel it's natural to define first and then use later - is it just me? Did I write a code that's against the intended design pattern?

I would like to understand how Express defines the name of param, and how `router.param` and `router.router` handle them.

Comment: `validateParamBeforeHandlingReqs` isn't called until a request is actually _received_, by which point all of the routes have also been registered. You might _never_ register a route with a parameter named `coolParamName`, in which case it just never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`router.param('coolParamName')` essentially registers a callback that will get called for any route (in that router) that uses the `:coolParamName` parameter and matches the current request.  The callback will get called once per request BEFORE the route that matches the request that contains the `:coolParamName` parameter.

It's kind of like middleware for a matching parameter.  It allows you to automatically configure some setup code anytime that particular parameter is matched in a route.

FYI, I expect that `router.param()` may be one of the least used features of Express since it can be accomplished many other ways, but it probably works best for validation-type code that checks named properties for validity before the route itself gets called.

You could accomplish the same thing by just using a piece of middleware on that specific route too or even just calling a function inside the route handler.  So, this is just a nicety feature if you happen to use the same parameter in multiple routes.